# Media player Can't Stop Playing

Tags: android

i am trying to play media file with the following code using floating action button.
it works fine so far but it keeps playing even when i switch to another activity. I want to stop media player when back button pressed. Please help me...
Here is the code:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sound);    
    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    final MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();            
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (mp.isPlaying()) {
                    mp.stop();
                }

                try {
                    mp.reset();
                    AssetFileDescriptor afd;
                    afd = getAssets().openFd("audio/sound.mp3");
                    mp.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
                    mp.prepare();
                    mp.start();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

    }
        @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
        //here i want to stop media player with back button
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override OnDestroy and add below code:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
   if (mp != null) mp.release();
}
```